# Allow form to submit (and post data) when form is invalid (i.e. use validation to show warning but not prevent form submission) using jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using validation to check some max / min values of some user inputs to a form, and if outside a certain range to warn the user.

However the user may wish to accept the warning and continue, I do not want the validation "failure" to prevent the user submitting the form and posting data.

Here is my validation code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#myform').validate({

        onkeyup: false,
        errorClass: 'authError',
        validClass:'success',
        errorElement: 'span',
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) 
        { 
        $(element).parents("div.question")
                  .addClass(errorClass)
                  .removeClass(validClass); 

        }, 
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass)
        {
        $(element).parents(".error")
                  .removeClass(errorClass)
                  .addClass(validClass); 
        },
        rules: {

       quantity_1: {
                    required: false,
                    number: true,
                    min: 0.2,
                    max: 0.2
                    }
                },

        messages:{
        quantity_1:
            {
                min: "Note: this is less than recommended",
                max: "Note: this is more than recommended"          
            }
        }
    });  
});
```

I tried adding the class "cancel" to the submit button, and this did allow the form navigation to occur (i.e. user could click the button and move to the next page) but it also seemed to prevent the form from posting the data (which is required).

Is there any way I can do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), you would set the `onsubmit` option to `false`.  In this scenario, you will see validation errors on every keystroke and on blur events, but if/when the user clicks the submit button, the form will submit despite any error messages.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#myform').validate({
        onsubmit: false,
        // your other options....
```

Since you've disabled key up validation with `onkeyup:false`, you will only see any validation errors when the field loses focus.

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to add $('#myform').submit(); to what ever it is the user clicks on to by pass the error.

Comment: Not with the jQuery Validation plugin.  For best results, use the options and callback functions provided by the plugin.